# Django template : begin-math/end-math missing symbol error

Tags: math-mode

I wrote a the following template in LaTeX:

```latex
% Projet   : INFOREFLEX_GENER_HTML
% Nom      : index_cellules.tex
% Auteur   : Emmanuel DUVSHANI
% Fonction : template pour l'affichage des cellules travaillant sur les applications PSA des périmètres ASSP et VTIS, de production et de pré-production
%            Le template est écrit en TeX, et est censé être converti et affiché en PDF.
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[margin=0.25in]{geometry}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=cyan,
}
\title{INFOREFLEX_GENER_HTML_CELLULES, version 1.0 (23/07/2019)}
\author{OPEN Emmanuel Duvshani}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\bigskip
(Date de l'import des données en base : {{ dateDernierExport }})
\bigskip
\newcolumntype{y}{>{\columncolor{yellow}}l}
{% for cellule in listeCellules %}
    \hypertarget"{"{{ cellule.dpt_im }}"}{"{{ cellule.dpt_im }}"}"
    \bigskip
    \begin{left}
    \begin{tabular}{ | y | }
    \hline
    {% with utilisateur=cellule.utilisateurs.all %}
        \hyperlink"{"http://annuaire-entreprise.inetpsa.com/?action=exec_recherche_personne&identifiant={{ utilisateur.cod_user }}"}{"{{ utilisateur.cod_user }}"}"-{{ utilisateur.lib_prenom }} {{ utilisateur.lib_nom_usuel }}
        \hline
    {% endwith %}
    \end{tabular}
    \end{left}
    \bigskip
{% endfor %}
\end{document}
```

Each time I try to run the application using this template, I get the following error message:

```
TexError at /inforeflex_gener_html/cellules

! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
$
l.31 \bigskip
I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think
you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed.

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/inforeflex_gener_html/cellules
Django Version:     2.2.2
Exception Type:     TexError
Exception Value:    

! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
$
l.31 \bigskip
I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think
you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed.

Exception Location:     C:\Users\edu04718\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django_tex\core.py in run_tex, line 26
Python Executable:  C:\Users\edu04718\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe
Python Version:     3.7.3
```

According to what I've understood, this means that I used a math-mode tag, that should be put between dollar signs. But I cannot see which math-mode tag I've used.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `\begin{left}` is essentially `\left`, which is a math command. You probably want `\begin{flushleft}`...`\end{flushleft}`.

Comment: Thank you, But I get the message error for a line which is much before in the template, the line containing "\bigskip". And even if I remove this line, I have the same error message. If I leave a blank line instead of "\bigskip", I get the error message on the blank line !

Comment: The error message says “line 39”, the one with `\begin{left}`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't put the right error message, I put the error message that I got when I tried to comment all the part before the table. The actual error message is:

TexError at /inforeflex_gener_html/cellules

! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
$
l.31 \bigskip
I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think
you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed.

Comment: I've fixed the question: I've put the right error message.

Comment: What does `{{ cellule.dpt_im }}` get replaced with? Can you provide the dataset with the replacement values?

Comment: What do you mean by "provide the dataset with the replacment values" ?

Anyway, the error is before.

Comment: The problem disappears when I comment the tag "\maketitle" ! I don't understand why.